# Palette not appearing for Activiti explorer

Tags: activiti

I have imported the source code of Activiti Explorer(Community Version 5.19.2) and after generating a war file manually out of the source code I'm deploying it in Tomcat 8.0.
Although the application pulls up fine, but the modeler window doesn't display the palette.

Any help in this regards would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running activiti-webapp-explorer2, then request should be like http://localhost:8080/activiti-webapp-explorer2/service/model/1522/json . You need to change the context root in the config. Go to Folder {TOMCAT_HOME}\webapps\activiti-webapp-explorer2\editor-app and then edit file app-cfg.js . Change config to

```
ACTIVITI.CONFIG = {
'contextRoot' : '/activiti-webapp-explorer2/service',
};
```

If ypu have source then find the app-cfg.js and change congfiuration.

For more discussion see [Activiti forum post](https://forums.activiti.org/content/activiti-webapp-explorer-palletetools-are-not-coming)